# How do I render List and Grid on the same page in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to render `GridView` and `ListView` on the same page in Flutter, where the grid and list are not scrollable on their own but are scrollable as a whole page. The `GridView` and the `ListView` will be rendered, but they should have a discontinuous distribution of grid and list on the page.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "render List and Grid on the same page" ? Can you elaborate more? provide a visual example would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use `primary: false` and `shrinkWrap: true` to the `GridView`

```
return ListView(
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      height: 75,
      color: Colors.green,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(25),
    ),
    GridView.count(
      primary: false,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      crossAxisCount: 3,
      children: List<Widget>
        .generate(10, (_) => Container(
            color: Colors.red,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(25),
      )),
    ),
  ],
);
```

Comment: For a better answer, you should explain what each of them does.